# How can I specify the .NET version in VSCode's tasks.json file?

Tags: .net, vscode-tasks

I have both .NET 9 preview and .NET 8 installed. Right now .NET 9 preview version is selected as the default.

I've learned that I can use `global.json` to specify the .NET version in command line, but the `tasks.json` file in VSCode doesn't recognize `global.json` and still uses the preview version as the build task. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my generated tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "dotnet",
            "task": "build",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "dotnet: build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's the content of your json files ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with task.json, but `"task": "build",` seems a invalid option, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix,  and what extension are you using?  C# Dev Kit ?

Comment: Yes C# Dev Kit.

Comment: What's the content of `global.json` ?  And you may try https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/cs-dev-kit-faq#_net-sdk , set `"dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath"."path"` to .net 8 exe file.

Comment: ```{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "8.0.101"
    }
}```